# NodeRED http in node appends charset=utf-8 even if set Content-Type to application/octet-stream

Tags: node-red

I tested NodeRED with the following steps.

- Put file.zip on NodeRED public folder
- Use browser to get this file directly via http://example.com/file.zip. It works fine.
- create HTTP In node to accept GET request from /file.zip
  [HTTP In node image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG6sv.jpg)
- create HTTP response node and set the following response headers
  [HTTP response node image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34uMJ.jpg)

  `Content-Disposition` to `attachment; filename= file.zip`

  `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream`
- When I request this url from browser, file.zip can be downloaded but it can not be opened (corrupted). When I look at network debugger tool on browser, I can see that the Content-Type response header is `application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8` whereas Content-Disposition is set as expected .

I found this issue (https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/1023) which has already been fixed in my NodeRED version 0.17.5 (latest). I am not sure if it is related to my problem or not.

I guess `charset=utf-8` is the culprit. How can I get rid of it to be able to download file.zip successfully via http-in node using `Content-Disposition:attachment; filename= file.zip`?

Comment: If you think this issue hasn't been fixed properly then it may be better to comment on the issue rather than a question here.

Comment: Also when you comment please include a small sample flow that shows the problem

Comment: Okay, I will post the comment there.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @hardillb, my flow did not send out any data. I have to use functionGlobalContext and readFileSync to load the content of the file before sending it to http response node.